# Network error in Jquery post

Tags: jquery, post

I am getting an error when doing a Jquery post (Error: A network error occurred.)

With Postman, it does work, here is the cURL:

```
POST /site/restapi/postalcode HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 14d39deb-fc28-3171-d688-18deaca7cbbe

{
"postalCode" : "9041AK",
"houseNumber" : "1"
}
```

Unfortunately with my javascript it does not:

```
$('input[name="houseNumber"]').blur(function() {
        // Check if the street and city can be fetched
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : "localhost:8080/site/restapi/postalcode",
            data: { postalCode : "9713GC", houseNumber : "1" },
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }}).fail(function(data, status, error) {
                console.log("error!" + error);
        });

    });
```

Edit: I have installed the firefox add-on Tamper Data, this gives insight to all requests being sent. This has given some additional information: no request is really being sent at all. (Apart from the GET request on loading the page.)

What is going on? Why does it not work?

Comment: Are you mixing http vs https by chance? Also is this a cross domain call?

Comment: No, it is not cross-domain. I added this, after all my other options had failed :-P. 
How can I be mixing up http vs https as it is on localhost?

Comment: Hey! You know how it goes, we have to ask even the stupidest questions just in case! :-). With postman you are using content-type but you are not setting that header on the AJAX call, have you tried setting that one up? ( the default is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8)

Comment: I have added the following: contentType : "application/json", (I will also update this in my question. Unfortunately the result is the same (network-error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `url`  in the request is wrong.

If you write `"localhost:8080/site/restapi/postalcode"`, then `localhost` will - depending on the implementation of the url parser - referrer to protocol or the path will interpreted as relative path, but then `localhost:8080` in both cases would not be interpreted as `host`.

You have to write one of the following:

- `"http://localhost:8080/site/restapi/postalcode"`
- `"https://localhost:8080/site/restapi/postalcode"`
- `"//localhost:8080/site/restapi/postalcode"`
- `"/site/restapi/postalcode"`

Which one depends on the url you initiate request from.